# Invalid Object Name 'Database1.Login'

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myconnection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\G_Anik\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Practise2\Practise2\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(myconnection);

        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select *from Database1.Login where UserName=' " + this.Username.Text + " ' and Password=' " + this.Password.Text + " ' ;", mycon);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        mycon.Open();
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UserName and Password is Correct");

        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password.. Access DEnied");

        }    
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is Incorrect.Try Again");
        mycon.Close();    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a collection of "how-not-to-do-this" lines of code. Please read a good book or tutorial on:

- SQL in general (your quotes are wrong)
- [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks (what happens if I put `'; DROP DATABASE; --` into your textbox? Or maybe just `' OR 1 == 1 --` ?)
- password security in the database. See [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).
- the [IDisposible interface and using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
 SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select *from Login where UserName=' " + this.Username.Text + " ' and Password=' " + this.Password.Text + " ' ;", mycon);
            SqlDataReader myReader;
```